# SPFX Webpart with Dropdown don't work on Classic pages

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, classic-experience

I currently have a spfx web-part which contains a dropdown, when I add it to a classic page and try to use the dropdown when the SharePoint ribbon displays the Format Text tab, the dropdown keeps closing it self. But if i remove the focus from a place with text (the format text tab is not shown on the ribbon anymore) the dropdown works perfectly. Is this a scenario that someone else experienced? I've been trying to